# Создание и удаление директорий и файлов в Linux kernel

Tags: linux, файлы, kernel

Пишу модуль ядра Linux. Требуется создать директории по пути `/etc/data_stor/user/id/{0001}`, `/etc/data_stor/user/id/{0002}`, `/etc/data_stor/user/id/{0003}`, `/etc/data_stor/user/id/{0004}`. В этих директориях создать одинаковый набор файлов с именами Name, Family, Age и т.д. и записать туда необходимую информацию.
Я создаю директории следующим образом:

```
const char* path = /etc/data_stor/user/id/{0001};
create_path(path);

static int dev_mkdir(const char *name, umode_t mode)
{
    struct dentry *dentry;
        struct path path;
        int err;

dentry = kern_path_create(AT_FDCWD, name, &path, LOOKUP_DIRECTORY);
if (IS_ERR(dentry))
    return PTR_ERR(dentry);

err = vfs_mkdir(d_inode(path.dentry), dentry, mode);
done_path_create(&path, dentry);
return err;
}

static int create_path(const char *nodepath)

    {
        char *path;
        char *s;
        int err = 0;

 path = kstrdup(nodepath, GFP_KERNEL);
if (!path)
    return -ENOMEM;

s = path;
for (;;) {
    s = strchr(s, '/');
    if (!s)
        break;
    s[0] = '\0';
    err = dev_mkdir(path, 0777);
    if (err && err != -EEXIST)
        break;
    s[0] = '/';
    s++;
}
kfree(path);
return err;
}
```

А файлы создаю функцией

```
hFile = filp_open(Path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);

if (IS_ERR(hFile))
{
    printk("write_dword open file failed %s %ld\n", Path, PTR_ERR(hFile));
    return PTR_ERR(hFile);
}
kernel_write(hFile, data, sizeof(DWORD), &foff);

filp_close(hFile, 0);
```

Директории и файлы с информацией успешно создаются, но имеются некоторые проблемы:

1. При удалении вручную из файлового менеджера директорий с файлами система иногда падает(kernel panic).
2. При попытке зачитать информацию из некоторых файлов функция `filp_open` возвращает ошибку -ENOENT. Не найден файл или директория, хотя они присутствуют.

Так же требуется удалять все директории при запросе с user-mode. Я написал функцию, но она удаляет только пустую директорию, т.е. в ней не должно быть файлов.

Прошу помочь с данными вопросами, объяснить в какую сторону двигаться, либо привести конкретный пример или литературу.

Comment: В linux вам необходимо применять механизм рекурсивного удаления.
См https://losst.ru/kak-udalit-katalog-linux

Comment: Непустой каталог нельзя удалить, это нормально. Сначала надо удалить из него все файлы.